# iPhone access to Springboard icons

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible for an app to access Springboard icons? I want to build a small animation where a ball is jumping over the icons over other apps.

Here's an example what I want to achieve.

Possible?

[image: Example]

Comment: If an app could do this, my list of people to hunt down and murder would likely grow quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible on iOS with the official SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Move to Android? No, i dont think iOS can w/o jailbreak.

Begs question - ios5? Whats gonna happen there? Maybe we will get widget framework, hopefully at a minimum something for the lock screen.

Comment: Yes a very good idea moving to android, that way skynet KUCH mean google can monitor you!

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted the effect you could have the user take a screenshot of their homescreen and use that in the animation, but thats the only way you could do that in the official SDK.